# Regex - how to replace css when not inside of html

Tags: javascript, html, regex, css

Alright, so I've been looking around for quite a while trying to figure out how to get this to work out. So what I'm trying to do is replace anything in strings that looks like this:

```
foo: bar;
```

But only if its not inside something like this:

```
<div style='foo: bar; ofoo: obar'>
```

So the basic idea is that I want to replace css when its not inside html style attributes. I understand that you can use a for loop and check it but I would like to do this with just the regex replace.

I'm using JavaScript Regex heres what my code attempt currently looks like:

```
\b(.*?):(|\s)(.*?);
```

https://regex101.com/r/LWohvu/1

Notes:
I understand that you could use a ^ to check if it starts with it but that only works for the first line.

If I didn't cover any needed any information please feel free to comment!

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839) even it concerns getting CSS out of it.

Comment: Are the preset requirements for the html element styles in the first place? It would be far easier to add and remove classes. Is it custom user styling or something like that being added at runtime? If that's the case you could add those custom styles to classes in a `<style>` section in the head on page load and set an `!important` attribute on them or something like that.

Comment: [`m` modifier](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_m.asp) makes `^` work for every line.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by that @AustinWinstanley Because I plan to color css as its typed in a contenteditable.

Comment: @horcrux I can do that however there is an issue with that, css allows users to have 1 line code for multiple attributes.

Comment: @trincot it is completely possible to highlight syntax with regex, I have done so before. It works without any issues. https://pastebin.com/Da14Wggd

Comment: So is the purpose to have a default style and then change the element style as the user types it into a textbox? What's unclear is where the original style is coming from and why you don't want to replace it? If it's the default style, you can move it into a class and use JS to add the style attribute to the element which will override the class.

Comment: Also, @trincot is right. While you 'can' parse HTML using regex, there are a lot of reasons not to. The link posted to the previous SO answer is one of the most popular SO answers of all time for a reason, and it isn't just because it's funny.

Comment: In a way I'm kind of doing that but a little differently. I have the styles as you are saying, but instead of using a textarea im using a contenteditable div then using regex to replace the text and put it back into the div. So ether way you do this you have to use regex or a for loop.

Comment: @AustinWinstanley for my purposes regex seems to be the best way for me to go at this point, If there is a way to replace css separately from html style attributes.

Comment: Ok, 3 things: 1. You don't have to use regex. 2. Why are you using a content editable div? You can style a textbox however you want and woudn't be able to tell any difference. And 3. I still don't understand the replacing part of what you're asking. Is there initial style? Or you just want to set the style of the element as they type?

Comment: You are right I dont have to use regex, but regex is faster than any other methods I have come across. Im using a div contenteditable with every line being a separate contenteditable div to speed things up + div contenteditable allows styling with colors. The reason I am doing replacing is because I want to change text colors as the user types. I already have the html part down, I'm just needing help on the css portion.

Comment: Well, I still don't understand why you don't want to change the style that's already there with the full length aggregated from the divs, but you could just add to it with JS doing something like `theStyledElement.style.cssText = (theStyledElement.style.cssText + theStyleDiv.innerHTML);` Edit: In this case I'm assuming the innerHTML will just be the text the user types in.

Comment: I'm not really trying to create a stylesheet. I'm trying to change syntax colors as the user types. Here's an example, https://cwiz.co Im trying to get the css portion of the code to color as the user types. So if the user types foo: bar; it will be <span class='var'>foo&lt;/span>: <span class='val'>bar</span>;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you want to replace all `style` in your `html page` except those are inside of a `html tag`. I've updated your `regex` and this worked according to your need. Please check this.

Regex:

```
^(?!(\=|\<))(.*?):(.*?);
```

Regex in JavaScript:

```
/^(?!(\=|\<))(.*?):(.*?);/gm
```

All style start with `style=` if this exists inside of a `html tag`. So, I've tried to avoid those using `^(?!(\=|\<))`. This represent not start with `=` and `<`. Avoid `=` for style and `<` for `html tag`.

Please check this in [Updated Regex](https://regex101.com/r/LWohvu/4).